# How to apply a transparency (focus?) ON pressing any item (as Google does)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view, android-custom-view

In the application "Google Play", we can see that if you click on any item (LinearLayout, button, imageview, textview ...) this has on it a blue coat.

Being above is not a simple background with android: state_pressed = "true" android: state_focused = "true" ...

Any idea how to apply that effect?

For example, I have a LinearLayout with multiple images and text.
This LinearLayout acts as a "button", my intention is that pressing change in appearance having a blue layer on top, as does Google.

I typically use custom background but that applies back and not over.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focus_blue_default" />
</selector>
```

And **focus_blue_default.xml**:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#8051C9EC" />
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth: Google is most likely populating a `GridView` with `android:drawSelectorOnTop` enabled. As a result, the selector doesn't act as 'background', but more like an 'overlay'. Unfortunately, this attribute is only available on extensions of `AbsListView`, and there is no generic way to apply it to any other view type. You're going to have to make an extension of every `View` you're interested in. Do set up some sort of a helper/util class for the actual logic, so you can leverage that in every extended view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only for reference and I do not think it is practical and it is not tested and ...

Since the answer is accepted, I will state the problems of this code (the ones I can think of right now):

1. As @user2558882 stated in his comment on the answer, if a subclass uses `setContentView(view, params)` the params are lost.
2. This will not work with inflated views -i.e. adapters; Yet, you can solve by calling `fix(View)` on any inflated view.
3. It only works with colors. This can be fixed as well.
4. I think this might work with sherlock-actionbar.
5. The code has not been tested so please test it.
6. It shifts your whole view tree one more level by adding a RelativeLayout. This can be fixed using `addContentView`. I did use this RelativeLayout because I answered this fast and I also think the current code will work better on all phones and apis. This is true because the whole solution is compacted in a RelativeLayout whose behavior is pretty consistent. After all I am only using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` which is the very basic functionality of this ViewGroup.

---

**Solution**

Create a **BaseActivity.java**:

```
package mobi.sherif.overlay;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout mRl;
    View mImage;
    View mContent;
    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(layoutResID, null));
    }
    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        setContentView(view, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }
    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, LayoutParams params) {
        mContent = view;
        fix(view);
        push(view);
    }
    protected void refix() {
        fix(mContent);
    }
    private void push(View view) {
        mRl = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mRl.addView(view, params);
        mImage = new View(this);
        mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0);
        mRl.addView(mImage, params);
        super.setContentView(mRl);
    }
    protected void fix(View child) {
        if (child == null)
            return;

        doFix(child);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            fix((ViewGroup) child);
        }
    }

    private void fix(ViewGroup parent) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            fix(parent.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
    private void doFix(View child) {
        if(child.getTag()!=null && child.getTag().getClass() == String.class) {
            String color = (String) child.getTag();
            int theColor;
            try {
                theColor = Color.parseColor(color);
                child.setTag(theColor);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                theColor = -1;
            }
            if(theColor != -1) {
                child.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            mImage.setBackgroundColor((Integer) v.getTag());
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mImage.getLayoutParams();
                            params.leftMargin = getLeftWithRespectTo(v, mRl);
                            params.topMargin = getTopWithRespectTo(v, mRl);
                            params.width = v.getWidth();
                            params.height = v.getHeight();
                            mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mImage.requestLayout();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        default:
                            break;
                        }
                        return v.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    private int getLeftWithRespectTo(View view, View relative) {
        int left = 0;
        View temp = view;
        do {
            left += temp.getLeft();
            temp = (View) temp.getParent();
        }
        while(temp!=relative);
        return left;
    }
    private int getTopWithRespectTo(View view, View relative) {
        int top = 0;
        View temp = view;
        do {
            top += temp.getTop();
            temp = (View) temp.getParent();
        }
        while(temp!=relative);
        return top;
    }
}
```

Now extend this BaseActivity and any view you want to overlay on it a color use `android:tag="#AARRGGBB"` like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="#331111ff"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

***TEST:*** If you use the xml up in **activity_main.xml** like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:tag="#331111ff"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And use this as your **MainActivity.java**:

```
package mobi.sherif.overlay;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.textView1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "text tpicjed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Another good answer, man. Its impressive that you can write this kind of a code without even testing it. I looked through it, the logic is sound. I'll be disappointed if `ephramd` does not go with this answer. Also, this ain't true: `I do not think it is practical`.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it a bit. All what am saying is that this is not the optimal solution, nor a good one. It might work though :P

Comment: I guess I see your answer a bit differently then. To me, this looks a one-time effort to afford functionality to the entire application. I can also see how this would avoid code repetition. One thing I want to ask: You are not using the `LayoutParams` being supplied in `setContentView(View view, LayoutParams params)`. So, will it be ok if you have `setContentView(view, null);` inside `setContentView(View view)`?

Comment: Ok that's what I mean. That is one mistake, the param passed down is lost somewhere. I will not touch the code now. By the way, I just remembered @user2558882 http://stackoverflow.com/a/18874519/833622

Comment: Amazing @SherifelKhatib! Is an excellent solution. Many answers have been very helpful but your answer is the simplest solution to my problem. Thank you all, I give you my reputation points.

Comment: I edited the answer to state some problems with it. Anyway, I am glad I was able to help.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib One thing I'm not convinced of this code is the use of `default tag`.

I'm trying to do:

`...
textview.setTag(R.id.colorOverlay,"#331111ff");
...`

And in class "BaseActivity"  replacement all `getTag()` by `getTag(R.id.colorOverlay)`.

However that does not work.

Comment: @ephramd Notice that the fix function is called in the beginning after inflation. If you want to use `setTag` programatically, fix should be called afterwards. If you do not want to call fix for each view, I will edit the answer and create a `refix()` that you can call after finishing the setTag calls. Gimme 1 minute

Comment: @ephramd I added the `refix` function. I made `refix` and `fix` protected instead of private.

Comment: I don't understand how to properly apply this class on a custom listview. I understand that I need to use `fix()`. I apply the setTag on listview ...

Comment: In your getView, before returning the view, call fix(view)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you want to achieve this effect on a `Button`:

1. Create a class which extends Android `Button` class
2. Have a boolean flag as a class member which will be set to `true` when you want this effect to appear (I would say that you can set it's value according to the touch events detected in `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` - just override it in your class and analyse those events).
3. Override `onDraw()` method, and after the call for the super, add an if clause which will paint this colored rect over the whole view (using `Paint`) if the boolean flag is true.

Few important points:

- Alternative to step 3: You can achieve the same effect by having a (semi transparent, blue) `drawable` which you will add or remove according to the flag.
- You may need to invalidate your view after changing the `boolean` value.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I'm trying to apply your instructions but this is a bit complicated. Especially because I would like to apply it to any view, and this signfica create a button class, LinearLayout, imageview, etc ...
Is not there something simpler like an over view?

Comment: I don't think this would be useful for layouts (from your example of Google Play it seems that you want to use it to emphasise that a view can be clicked). You can also add this as an overlay image (and play with it's visibility), but that would be less convenient in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be exactly what you're asking for, I did come up with an easily reusable way to make controls semi-transparent when pressing on them, then have them return to their normal display when you stop pressing on them.

Here's the code:

```
public class ViewTouchHighlighter implements OnTouchListener 
{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0.5f);
            animation.setDuration(0);
            v.startAnimation(animation);

        }
        else
        {
            AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f, 1);
            animation.setDuration(0);
            v.startAnimation(animation);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then, you can simply grab any view, and give it this behavior like so:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new ViewTouchHighlighter());
```

I realize this is a bit off from what you're looking for, but if highlighting is all you want, this could serve as a nice solution.

If you're insisting on the blue effect, and/or you want something that appears blue when selected, not when simply touched, then I'm afraid I'm going to agree with @Daniel & suggest that you inherit from any component you might want to do this with and add your custom code there.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the container layout (for individual items) being used on Google play is a RelativeLayout. And achieving this effect is fairly simple using a RelativeLayout. You already have most of the components ready. Here's the final step:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <ImageView 
    ........../>

    <TextView 
    ........../>

    <WhateverView 
    ........../>

    <!--     The final piece -->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/clickableView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/state_selector_drawable" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And, in your activity, you will be adding an OnClickListener to this View:

```
View clickableView = findViewById(R.id.clickableView);

clickableView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                 "Click registered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

});
```

Let's say you already have a LinearLayout set up and do not wish to switch over to RelativeLayout. That's fine. Place the LinearLayout along with its children inside a RelativeLayout. And add the View defined above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >


        <ImageView 
        ........../>

        <TextView 
        ........../>

        <WhateverView 
        ........../>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--     The final piece -->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/clickableView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/state_selector_drawable" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Probably this this is the easiest solution. However, touch events will be consumed by the overlay.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib That shouldn't be a problem. OP said: `[this] LinearLayout acts as a "button"`. In this case, the `View` will act as a button.